# how to pass a pandas dataframe column from datetime to time (HH:MM:SS) in python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, time

I have a df that looks like this:

```
           date          arrival_time       departure_time
0     2021-01-16  2021-01-16 16:58:16  2021-01-16 21:02:19
1     2021-01-16  2021-01-16 22:34:04  2021-01-16 22:34:51
2     2021-01-27  2021-01-27 16:01:21  2021-01-27 16:02:22
3     2021-01-07  2021-01-07 11:57:08  2021-01-07 14:22:15
4     2021-01-07  2021-01-07 12:20:54  2021-01-07 13:41:43
```

`date`, `arrival_time` and `departure_time` columns are `datetime64[ns]` columns. What I want to do is to convert `arrival_time` and `departure_time` columns to `time` with this format: `HH:MM:SS`. Therefore, my desired output should look something like this:

```
         date     arrival_time   departure_time 
0     2021-01-16    16:58:16      21:02:19
1     2021-01-16    22:34:04      22:34:51
2     2021-01-27    16:01:21      16:02:22
3     2021-01-07    11:57:08      14:22:15
4     2021-01-07    12:20:54      13:41:43
```

I've tried this code:

```
df["arrival_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrival_time']).dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
df["departure_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df['departure_time']).dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

And I've also tried this one:

```
df['arrival_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrival_time'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

However both approaches return a string, not a `time` object. If someone knows how to do that I would really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Probably easier with `timedelta`: `df['arrival_time'] = df['arrival_time'] - df['arrival_time'].dt.normalize()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the values as `'datetime.time'` object you can use `.time` like so:

```py
df["arrival_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrival_time'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").dt.time
df["departure_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df['departure_time'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").dt.time

print(df)
print(df['departure_time'][0].__class__) # print element class
```

**Output:**

```
         date arrival_time departure_time
0  2021-01-16     16:58:16       21:02:19
1  2021-01-16     22:34:04       22:34:51
2  2021-01-27     16:01:21       16:02:22
3  2021-01-07     11:57:08       14:22:15
4  2021-01-07     12:20:54       13:41:43
<class 'datetime.time'>
```

Comment: it is a `datetime` object but the output is the same as my initial data: `2021-01-16 16:58:16`, i.e. not my desired output.

Comment: @brenda understood your requirement, I've updated the answer. Does it help?

Comment: not really, when doing df.info() I'm getting an `object` type :(

Comment: @brenda try `df['departure_time'][0].__class__` it returns `<class 'datetime.time'>` is it not want you need?

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to `split()` the string by column and then apply the `datetime` conversion over pandas dataframe specific columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import datetime as dt

# splitting strings #
df['arrival_time'] = df['arrival_time'].str.split(' ', expand=True)[1]
df['departure_time'] = df['departure_time'].str.split(' ', expand=True)[1]

# converting to specific datetime format #

df["arrival_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrival_time'],format="%H:%M:%S")
df["departure_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df['departure_time'], format="%H:%M:%S")
```

Console output:

```
#   date      arrival_time  departure_time
#0  2021-01-16  16:58:16    21:02:19
```

### data

```
d = {'date': ['2021-01-16'], 'arrival_time': ['2021-01-16 16:58:16'], 'departure_time':['2021-01-16 21:02:19']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```